# two modals on a page but only one opens for all actions in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a page in which i pop open a confirmation modal when the user wants to reset the form and then another confirmation modal when the user deletes and item of the page. Current issue is that only one modal is being opened for both actions and not sure why.

Is there a rule that there could be one modal per page or something?

This is what i have in my component:

```
@ViewChild(ModalComponent)
    private resetDialog: ModalComponent;
    private removeDialog: ModalComponent;

private openResetDialog() {
        this.resetDialog.open();
    }

private resetDialogConfirmed() {
    this.reset();
    this.resetDialog.close();
}

private resetDialogDeclined() {
    this.resetDialog.close();
}

private openRemoveDialog() {
    this.removeDialog.open();
}

private removeDialogConfirmed(item: number) {
    this.onRemove(item);
    this.removeDialog.close();
}

private removeDialogDeclined() {
    this.removeDialog.close();
}
```

In my html page i have:

```
<confirmation-modal #resetDialog [title]="resetMessage">
        <div>
            <button type="button" (click)="resetDialogConfirmed()">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" (click)="resetDialogDeclined()">No</button>
        </div>
    </confirmation-modal>

    <confirmation-modal #removeDialog [title]="removeMessage">
        <div>
            <button type="button"(click)="removeDialogConfirmed(i)">Yes</button>
            <button type="button"(click)="removeDialogDeclined()">No</button>
        </div>
    </confirmation-modal>
```

This is the button i have to trigger the reset:

```
  <button (click)="openResetDialog()">Reset</button>
```

and this is what i have to trigger the remove:

```
 <a (click)="openRemoveDialog()">Remove</a>
```

when i click on both - the reset dialog is what opens up.

Comment: if you want to have a reference of the modal, you can write (click)="open(resetDialog)" or (click)="open(removeDialog)" (That's work because you are using #resetDialog and #removeDialog)

Answer (score 0):

@ViewChild works only for one child, you should use @ViewChildren.

For more information please follow the article below:

https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

Comment: Indeed Nour is right use children when you implement the same component multiple time with different behavior

Comment: I converted to using @ViewChildren and now with `@ViewChildren(ModalComponent) openDialog: QueryList<ModalComponent>;` but now i am getting this error when i try to pop modal dialog that `.open()` does not exist on type `QueryList<ModalComponent>`

Comment: You should iterate on the query list

Comment: @ViewChildren('bkWriter') 
allWriters: QueryList<WriterComponent> 

this.allWriters.forEach(writer => console.log(writer.writerName + ' - ' + writer.bookName));  @bluePearl